# Swift Calculate MD5 Checksum for Large Files

Tags: ios, swift, md5, checksum, commoncrypto

I'm working on creating the MD5 Checksum for large video files. I'm currently using the code:

```
extension NSData {
func MD5() -> NSString {
    let digestLength = Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH)
    let md5Buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.allocate(capacity: digestLength)

    CC_MD5(bytes, CC_LONG(length), md5Buffer)
    let output = NSMutableString(capacity: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2))
    for i in 0..<digestLength {
        output.appendFormat("%02x", md5Buffer[i])
    }

    return NSString(format: output)
    }
}
```

But that creates a memory buffer, and for large video files would not be ideal. Is there a way in Swift to calculate the MD5 Checksum reading a file stream, so the memory footprint will be minimal?

Comment: Look into using the right combination of `CC_MD5_Init`, `CC_MD5_Update`, and `CC_MD5_Final`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can compute the MD5 checksum in chunks, as demonstrated 
e.g. in [Is there a MD5 library that doesn't require the whole input at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988369/is-there-a-md5-library-that-doesnt-require-the-whole-input-at-the-same-time).

Here is a possible implementation using Swift (now updated for Swift 5)

```
import CommonCrypto

func md5File(url: URL) -> Data? {

    let bufferSize = 1024 * 1024

    do {
        // Open file for reading:
        let file = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: url)
        defer {
            file.closeFile()
        }

        // Create and initialize MD5 context:
        var context = CC_MD5_CTX()
        CC_MD5_Init(&context)

        // Read up to `bufferSize` bytes, until EOF is reached, and update MD5 context:
        while autoreleasepool(invoking: {
            let data = file.readData(ofLength: bufferSize)
            if data.count > 0 {
                data.withUnsafeBytes {
                    _ = CC_MD5_Update(&context, $0.baseAddress, numericCast(data.count))
                }
                return true // Continue
            } else {
                return false // End of file
            }
        }) { }

        // Compute the MD5 digest:
        var digest: [UInt8] = Array(repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        _ = CC_MD5_Final(&digest, &context)

        return Data(digest)

    } catch {
        print("Cannot open file:", error.localizedDescription)
        return nil
    }
}
```

The autorelease pool is needed to release the memory returned by
`file.readData()`, without it the entire (potentially huge) file
would be loaded into memory. Thanks to Abhi Beckert for noticing that
and providing an implementation.

If you need the digest as a hex-encoded string then change the
return type to `String?` and  replace

```
return digest
```

by

```
let hexDigest = digest.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
return hexDigest
```

Comment: For anyone using this code, you'll want to update to match the edit I just made as it was storing the entire file in the current autorelease pool, potentially consuming tens of gigabytes of memory.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: Indeed, that makes a huge difference. Thanks for the update! I have modified the code a bit to get rid of the additional exit variable, but that is purely a matter of personal choice.

Comment: Excellent answer! Is there a simple way to get the progress while it's running? Say, to update the user in the UI.

Comment: Thanks. But, why such the important `autoreleasepool` technique, never mentioned in documentation - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle/1413916-readdata ? Is it mentioned elsewhere?

Comment: @CheokYanCheng: `FileHandle` is the Swift name for the Objective-C `NSFileHandle` from the Foundation framework. Autorelease pools are only needed when interacting with Cocoa APIs. For Objective-C they are documented here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html.

Comment: If I didn't come across your code snippet, I would use `FileHandle` without autorelease. This morning, I try to run a testing and profiling, over a loop which perform file I/O and image scaling operation, I found with/ without `autoreleasepool` doesn't yield much different in memory usage pattern. Do you know what the thought process should be, to decide `autoreleasepool` usage? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68826618/how-can-we-decide-whether-we-should-use-autoreleasepool

Answer (score 8):

Since iOS13

> 'CC_MD5_Init' was deprecated in iOS 13.0

You may replace the code with `CryptoKit`

```
import Foundation
import CryptoKit

extension URL {

    func checksumInBase64() -> String? {
        let bufferSize = 16*1024

        do {
            // Open file for reading:
            let file = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: self)
            defer {
                file.closeFile()
            }

            // Create and initialize MD5 context:
            var md5 = CryptoKit.Insecure.MD5()
            
            // Read up to `bufferSize` bytes, until EOF is reached, and update MD5 context:
            while autoreleasepool(invoking: {
                let data = file.readData(ofLength: bufferSize)
                if data.count > 0 {
                    md5.update(data: data)
                    return true // Continue
                } else {
                    return false // End of file
                }
            }) { }

            // Compute the MD5 digest:
            let data = Data(md5.finalize())
            
            return data.base64EncodedString()
        } catch {
            error_log(error)
            
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution (based on Martin R's answer) for SHA256 hash:

```
func sha256(url: URL) -> Data? {
    do {
        let bufferSize = 1024 * 1024
        // Open file for reading:
        let file = try FileHandle(forReadingFrom: url)
        defer {
            file.closeFile()
        }

        // Create and initialize SHA256 context:
        var context = CC_SHA256_CTX()
        CC_SHA256_Init(&context)

        // Read up to `bufferSize` bytes, until EOF is reached, and update SHA256 context:
        while autoreleasepool(invoking: {
            // Read up to `bufferSize` bytes
            let data = file.readData(ofLength: bufferSize)
            if data.count > 0 {
                data.withUnsafeBytes {
                    _ = CC_SHA256_Update(&context, $0, numericCast(data.count))
                }
                // Continue
                return true
            } else {
                // End of file
                return false
            }
        }) { }

        // Compute the SHA256 digest:
        var digest = Data(count: Int(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        digest.withUnsafeMutableBytes {
            _ = CC_SHA256_Final($0, &context)
        }

        return digest
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return nil
    }
}
```

Usage with instance of type `URL` with name `fileURL` previously created:

```
if let digestData = sha256(url: fileURL) {
    let calculatedHash = digestData.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
    DDLogDebug(calculatedHash)
}
```