# swift: SHA1 from file without copy it to ram memory

Tags: swift, file, encryption, sha1

I'm downloading file (~ 300MB) using Alamofire.
After download and save, I have to calculate and compare SHA1 from this file, so I do this:

```
let data = Data(contentsOf: url)
let sha1 = data.sha1
```

That generate a problem. All bytes are coped to ram memory. How can I avoid this?

function to calculate:

```
extension Data {
    func sha1() -> String {
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count:Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        self.withUnsafeBytes {
            _ = CC_SHA1($0, CC_LONG(self.count), &digest)
        }
        let hexBytes = digest.map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }
        return hexBytes.joined()
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [Swift Calculate MD5 Checksum for Large Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42935148/swift-calculate-md5-checksum-for-large-files). The same approach works with SHA1 and other digests.

Comment: Information about how to map files into virtual memory can be found in Apple's Documentation https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemAdvancedPT/MappingFilesIntoMemory/MappingFilesIntoMemory.html

Comment: I've marked this as a dupe as I don't see the value of listing the same solution for each and every hash (there are 6 additional SHA-2 hashes and 4 additional SHA-3 hashes)

Comment: Note that neither MD5 nor SHA-1 are considered secure anymore, especially when it comes to hashing data structures (files) or signature generation. Both require that collisions are hard to calculate.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I don't agree with your action. I'm looking for a solution for SHA-1 algorithm. And it would be cool, if someone could share that.

Comment: I don't agree. But feel free to vote to reopen (rather than start a discussion in the comments).