# Md5 for a zip file and iCloud data backup

Tags: objective-c, ios, icloud

I am calling a web services in an iOS application which returns a URL to download a zip file of a book and its MD5 checksum. I would like to check the integrity of the file by calculating its MD5 checksum for comparison.

1. How can I calculate it? The file is a .zip file and it is stored in `Documents`.
2. The second question is: I would like to prevent files, such as books, htmpl files, from being backed up to iCloud and iTunes, I saw that there is a solution with iOS 5.1 and later but I would like to put my application to users with iOS 5.0. Is there a solution for this? Can I put the books downloaded in Cashes?

Comment: Please only ask one question per page. That helps keep the answers on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MD5 is available on the iPhone and can be added as an extension for  `NSString` and `NSData` like below.  You can also use this same method with OSX.

[MD5 algorithm in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524604/md5-algorithm-in-objective-c)