# MD5 Heaping Using IOS Exactly Like Java

Tags: ios, md5

This is my Code in java.Here I am converting a string to byte array and heaping it using MD algorithm with the Help of digest in java.

public static byte[] passwordToKey (String password) {

```
    MessageDigest md = null;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance ("MD5");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        return new byte[0];
    }
    byte[] passwordBytes = null;
    try {
        passwordBytes = password.getBytes ("ISO-8859-1");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
        passwordBytes = new byte[0];
    }
    return md.digest(passwordBytes);
}
```

The problem is the value after encryption in java and ios are different.Can someone give me the exact code in ios for the above?

Comment: How did you do that in iOS ?

Comment: I Want to implement it in IOS

Comment: Hope this link will help :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524604/md5-algorithm-in-objective-c