# how to use md5 format retrieved from json in iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ios9, md5

I've never used md5 format and i don't know how to decode it to get the string that is in response. How can i get the string from the md5 format?
I'm using swift language on Xcode for iOS app development. If there is any library that can be used please do suggest it.

TIA

Comment: MD5 is a "hash" or "message digest", *not* an encoding.

Comment: @MartinR how can i use it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *decode* MD5. What you can do instead is comparing the MD5 string from your JSON with a MD5(stringInYourApp). That means that if you want to compare the user input (for example) and the MD5 from your JSON you'll have to :

- Make a MD5 version of user input string ([see here for how to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994690/4894980))
- Compare it with the MD5 from JSON

**You cannot see the original string from a MD5 hash**.

Comment: Thanks a million for the info on the md5.

Answer (score 2):

That's why its MD5 hashing. You cannot decode it. It is more secured than simple string. Few years ago all passwords were encoded to MD5 because of security.

Comment: @EricD Then how md5 is used in the app.