# MD5 on Mac application?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, md5

I want to <s>encrypt</s> hash some strings with MD5 in my Mac application.

I Googled about it, but it keeps throwing me examples on how to do it with iPhone apps, like [MD5 algorithm in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524604/md5-algorithm-in-objective-c) or [Using MD5 hash on a string in cocoa?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652300/using-md5-hash-on-a-string-in-cocoa)...

Comment: MD5 is not an encryption algorithm; it's a hash. You can't encrypt with it.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that's what I meant. How do I make an MD5 hash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MD5 is **not encryption!**. Please see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

All of your examples do in fact work on OS X. CommonCrypto is part of libSystem. For a more complete example, I suggest this CocoaWithLove tutorial (and sample code!)

http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/07/hashvalue-object-for-holding-md5-and.html

Comment: CommonCrypto is not part of Foundation; it is part of libSystem. That difference aside, both libraries are available on both OSs.

Answer (score 2):

MD5 is not encryption is just a unique string (that you usually store in a hash table) calculated from a stream (that could your text, image, sound, data, etc)

Here is sample I used:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h>

const char *cStr = [someNSString UTF8String];
unsigned char resultChar[16];
CC_MD5( cStr, strlen(cStr), resultChar);
NSString *md5 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X",
                 resultChar[0], resultChar[1], resultChar[2], resultChar[3], 
                 resultChar[4], resultChar[5], resultChar[6], resultChar[7],
                 resultChar[8], resultChar[9], resultChar[10], resultChar[11],
                 resultChar[12], resultChar[13], resultChar[14], resultChar[15]];
```

Now just use the `md5` var for your purposes :)